# Postgres does not pick partial index even when the clause matches

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that looks like so:

```
  Column   |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default
-----------+---------+-----------+----------+---------
 app_id    | uuid    |           | not null |
 entity_id | uuid    |           | not null |
 attr_id   | uuid    |           | not null |
 value     | text    |           | not null |
 ea_index  | boolean |           |          |
Indexes:
    "triples_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (app_id, entity_id, attr_id, value)
    "ea_index" UNIQUE, btree (app_id, entity_id, attr_id) WHERE ea_index
    "triples_app_id" btree (app_id)
    "triples_attr_id" btree (attr_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "triples_app_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (app_id) REFERENCES apps(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    "triples_attr_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (attr_id) REFERENCES attrs(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

I have a special partial index `ea_index`, enabled for all the rows that have this column.

Now, when I run:

```
EXPLAIN (
  SELECT 
    * 
  FROM triples 
  WHERE 
    app_id = '6b1ca162-0175-4188-9265-849f671d56cc' AND
    entity_id = '6b1ca162-0175-4188-9265-849f671d56cc' AND 
  ea_index
);
```

I get:

```
 Index Scan using triples_app_id on triples  (cost=0.28..4.30 rows=1 width=221)
   Index Cond: (app_id = '6b1ca162-0175-4188-9265-849f671d56cc'::uuid)
   Filter: (ea_index AND (entity_id = '6b1ca162-0175-4188-9265-849f671d56cc'::uuid))
(3 rows)
```

I am a bit confused: *why* is this not using an index scan on `ea_index`? How could I debug this further?

Comment: Since only one row is expected to match anyway, what would be the point in trying to make it more selective?

Comment: Here, more than one row could match. The unicity constraint for the table is (app_id, entity_id, attr_id, value), but attr_id and value are not filtered in the query.

Comment: Ah! I see -- I was using a dummy uuiid. I think perhaps postgres knows there were no items in the table, so it just picked any scan. Thank you jjanes! I tested with an app id with rows and it picked ea_index.

Comment: It is a costing decision, not a correctness decision.  That more than one *can* match isn't important, it is how many are *expected* to match which matters for costing.  But it is possible that it expects more rows to match the index, but to be removed by the filter.  What happens if you repeat the query plan without the entity_id condition?

Comment: Okay, this makes a lot of sense! Thanks jjanes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was because of a costing decision. `EXPLAIN` showed that it expected only 1 row, so there was no difference which index it chose. Changing up the uuids, it *did* pick the correct index.